# ASP.NET and Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, web-config

I have a completed website, built with ASP.NET. I am trying to add Crystal Reports application as a link on one of the pages. Both Crystal Reports and the current website feed from the same database. When I incorporate the link on the page...I get this: Line 23:        Line 26:           
Line 27:

Source File:  X:\inetpub\wwwroot\awp\crystal1\crystal1\web.config    Line:  25

the error appears to be in the config file here but OP is not sure

```
<compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"> 
<assemblies> 
  <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /> 
  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
  <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /> 
</assemblies> 
</compilation> 
<authentication mode="Forms"> <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" /> 
</authentication>
```

I could appreciate a little help here. Thanks

Comment: are you using a mapped drive in regards to `X:\` can you show how you have this defined in the .config file as well?

Comment: On the local machine it is mapped to the "X" Drive, but on the server it is not pointing back to the local drive. The Crystal Reports program works fine on it's own and the Customer Portal site works fine on it's own. I am just trying to merge the two together from the same site. Since they have separate web configs, was thinking this was a problem. I was able to take non-conflicting or duplicated parts from CR and add to the Customer Portal wabconfig file and seemed to work until uploaded to the live site.

Comment: makes me wonder then instead of trying to access it at hte wwwroot level I would hope that perhaps you have a virtual directory setup for this on the live site.. if that's not relevant then I would look into read/write permissions for the IISUser perhaps.. local settings are not always going to migrate and or be the same for remote.. what's your admin say?

Comment: Virtual Directory was set-up and everything seems to be pointing in the right direction. Admin says IIS permissions are correct. The ASP.NET code is fine or I would not be able to use it on the local side. Something is changed when it goes to the LIVE application...just getting frustrated.

Comment: <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
   </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>

Comment: This looks like where the error takes place.

Comment: if you comment this line out does it work? `<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /> 
</assemblies>`

Comment: Better, still getting   500 - Internal server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: that's a .dll issue and or reference.. how about setting the properties of the .dll's that you need to copy local=true, or create a Lib folder and drop all the 3rd party .dll's there and delete the existing references and re-add them pointing to the dll's in the Lib folder.. make sure that the folder has full read / write permissions on the web server as well..

Comment: Will try it and let you know if it was the issue.

Comment: Got side-tracked yesterday and tried this morning. Now the whole site is getting 500 server error...may need to undo comment out section. frustrating.

Comment: uncommenting tag allows rest of site to work and back to authentication error when trying to open Crystal Reports.